# Dynamically calculate and display the sum of all tr element

Tags: javascript, jquery

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KrN7Z/13/)

I am trying to dynamically calculate and display the sum of all `tr` element whenever a user enters the value of quantity field in my case.

Can someone fix error in my code.

Jquery code:

```
$("table input").on('change blur input', function() {
var val = this.value;
$(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(4)').text(function(){
    return (+$.trim($(this).siblings(':eq(3)').text()) * +val)   
 })
$('table  tr td:nth-of-type(5)').each(function() {
        sum += parseFloat($(this).text().slice(1));
    });
    $('.sum').text(sum);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you need to declare the `sum` variable
2. the `parseFloat($(this).text().slice(1))` will return `NaN` when there is not text
3. why do you use the `slice(1)` ? you need to parse the whole text.

So

```
$("table input").on('change blur input', function () {
    var val = this.value;
    var sum = 0;
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(4)').text(function () {
        return (+$.trim($(this).siblings(':eq(3)').text()) * +val)
    });
    $('table  tr td:nth-of-type(5)').each(function () {
        sum += parseFloat($(this).text()) || 0;
    });
    $('.sum').text(sum);
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/KrN7Z/18/

---

**Better Approach**

But you should give some classes to some elements in your HTML and it would simplify everything a lot..

```
    <tr>
        <td>someno</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Some Name" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="quantity" placeholder="Quantity" />
        </td>
        <td class="price">50</td>
        <td class="total"></td>
        <td>something</td>
    </tr>
```

and

```
$("table input").on('change blur input', function () {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr'),
        quantity = +row.find('.quantity').val(),
        price = parseFloat(row.find('.price').text());

    row.find('.total').text(quantity * price);

    var sum = 0;
    $('.total').each(function () {
        sum += parseFloat($(this).text()) || 0;
    });

    $('.sum').text(sum);
});
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/KrN7Z/22/

Comment: i did not assigned class because i am having around 70 rows. btw awesum answer

Comment: @user2847429, the classes can be common on all rows.. so just copy/paste whole rows to replicate..

Comment: Actually i am working on Django project and using formset. server is sending me around 70 rows without any class assigned. it will be complicated for me to assign class using javascript in front end and then resend the form to server.

Comment: @user2847429 ok.. i thought you might be using some template that could be altered at a single point..

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You need to declare sum, and you need to handle the NaN case.

```
var sum = 0;
$('table  tr td:nth-of-type(5)').each(function() {
    var m = parseFloat($(this).text().slice(1));
    if (!isNaN(m)) {
        sum += m;
    }
});
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: That has to do more with the rest of the code than the summing part, though. Be careful with your selectors and UI state. For instance, don't create that event on all input elements - just the ones for quantity.

Comment: Sorry, my break is over. :\

Answer (score 0):

As already noted you need to declare `sum`, handle `NaN` cases and update the total value on every input. Try this:

```
 $("table input").on('change blur input', function () {
    var val = this.value;
    var sum = 0;
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(4)').text(function () {
        return (+$.trim($(this).siblings(':eq(3)').text()) * +val);
    });
    $('table  tr td:nth-of-type(5)').each(function () {
        var k = parseFloat($(this).text());
        sum +=  isNaN(k)?0:k;
        $('.sum').text(sum);
    });
});
```